# How to upload an image from client side form to Google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, webapp2

There is a form that uploads an image. Now I want to store it in Google cloud storage and get back to print on page. The form is : -

```
<form action="http://master-engine-799.appspot.com/uploadimage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

and the .py file is

```
import webapp2
import logging

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers


class UploadImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
  def post(self):        
# code that will upload the image to my bucket on cloud storage    
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload',gs_bucket_name='userimagebucket')

class UploadImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # code to show uploaded image in bucket
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/uploadimage', UploadImageHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import cloudstorage as gcs

import webapp2
import logging

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers



def CreateFile(filename,imageFile):
  with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg') as f:
    f.write(imageFile)
    f.close()


  blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename
  return blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

class MyImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
      def post(self):
        bucket='yourbucketname'
        imageFile = self.request.get('file')
        naemofFile=self.request.get('filename1')
        fileName='/yourbucketname'+'/'+naemofFile
        blob_key = CreateFile(fileName,imageFile)
        logging.info("Blob-Key "+blob_key)
        imageUrl = 'https://%(bucket)s.storage.googleapis.com/%(file)s' % {'bucket':bucket, 'file':naemofFile}

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/myimagehandler', MyImageHandler)],
                                  debug=True)
```

and the form is like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://your-app-id.appspot.com/myimagehandler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file"><br>
File Name : <input type="text" name="filename1">   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The upload_url provided by create_upload_url is the URL you want to use as the "action" on the form itself, rather than /uploadimage. So your HTML form should look more like:

```
<form action="CONTENTS_OF_UPLOAD_URL_HERE" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your upload handler can then redirect the user to the page showing the results. Example:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Comment: actually the form is on client side. From the form it will call the service . Then how i will provide the upload_url bcause it will be created dynamicaly...